# Angular13 with rxjs 7.4 and TS 4+ gives error....Could not find a declaration file for module 'rxjs'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am starting a new Angular app with V13 and rxjs7.4 which is giving me the above error on:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
```

At first I followed the suggestion to create a typings.d.ts declaration but though the error went away another error appeared...on further research I found this comment relating to V12:

*zijianhuang commented on May 17

> Angular 12 with rxjs 7.0.1 could be built and run, however, the VS IDE could not check reference. And tsconfig with strict=true has NG CLI complaining no reference to rxjs could be found and suggesting downloading type info.*

So I set strict-false in my tsconfig and now my rxjs error is gone. The question I have is this is obviously a temp solution. Is there a permanent fix to this?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of resolving this issue is using @types from npm. The command is as follows:

```js
npm install @types/rx --save-dev
```

For more information, see [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/rx).

Comment: Sorry this answer gave the same error.